# Generate API documentation using spring boot graphql spqr library

Tags: graphql, graphql-spqr

We are using Spring boot grphql sqpr library.
We have to generate graphql API documentation which can be viewed in graphiql.

For e.g.
If i have field like below

```
# comma separated location IDs. (eg: '5,12,27')
        locationIds: String
```

then this string `comma separated location IDs. (eg: '5,12,27')` should be visible in graphiql.

Answer (score 1):

You can attach a description to any schema element that permits it via its corresponding annotation:

- `@GraphQLQuery(description="...")` for output fields at any level
- `@GraphQLMutation(description="...")` for mutations
- `@GraphQLSubscription(description="...")` for subscriptions
- `@GraphQLInputField(description="...")` for input fields at any level, falls back to `@GraphQLQuery`
- `@GraphQLArgument(description="...")` for arguments
- `@GraphQLType/GraphQLInterface/GraphQLUnion(description="...")` - for descriptions on various kinds of types
- `@GraphQLDirective(description="...")` - for descriptions on directives

In short, the rule is: if it permits a descriptions in the schema, there's a corresponding annotation for it with a `description` parameter.

These are **only the defaults**, of course, you can always customize how descriptions are added, and how anything is mapped in general.